# OpenPyxl: read input file and make output matrix using list or array

Tags: python, openpyxl

Please help me to parse a file using OpenPyxl.

I have an excel file like below:

Input xlsx:

```
   A      B      C
1 Tom    Red    True
2 Tom    Red    False
3 Marry  Green  False
4 Marry  Green  True
5 Babara Red    False
```

A+B could be a key to removing duplicate values. (e.g. Marry+Green, Tom+Red)
Read Input file and make output file like below:

Expected output xlsx:

```
   A      B        Result
1 Tom    Red    True,False
2 Marry  Green  False,True
3 Babara Red    False
```

** value "True,False" in 1st row.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
import collections
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb1 = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1['test']
a_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for row in ws1.rows:
    a_dict[row[0].value+','+row[1].value].append(str(row[2].value))

wb2 = Workbook(write_only=True)
ws2 = wb2.create_sheet()
for key,value in a_dict.items():
    temp = key.split(',')
    temp.append(','.join(value))
    ws2.append(temp)
wb2.save('new_test.xlsx')
```

`new_test.xlsx` will be:

[image]

Comment: While this would work, this is also the kind of operation at which Pandas excels. http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandas.html

Comment: @CharlieClark yep, if so, read data to a dataframe, then it will be much easier to merge the data.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you for your help :) Could you explain this code briefly?

Comment: @Tiny.D how can I count the number of value of the "C" ?? (e.g. D1 = 1, D2 =2, D3=3)